# how to write variable in django template

Tags: django, templates

```
{% for card in cards %}
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{rankHash}}</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
```

This is my template view. 
cards query just like below.

```
<QuerySet [<Card: Card object (2)>, <Card: Card object (10)>, <Card: Card object (6)>, <Card: Card object (1)>, <Card: Card object (9)>, <Card: Card object (5)>, <Card: Card object (4)>, <Card: Card object (7)>, <Card: Card object (3)>, <Card: Card object (8)>, <Card: Card object (11)>]>
```

if I print `{{card.furniture}}` , output is some integer like `155`

`{{rankHash}}` print
 `{155: 1, 142: 2, 129: 3, 128: 4, 125: 5, 120: 6, 117: 7, 110: 8, 109: 9, 108: 10, 60: 11}`

So, I want to print key `1` by value `155`. But if i type `{{rankHash[155]}}`, below error appear.

> Could not parse the remainder: '[155]' from 'rankHash[155]'

I also already know if i type `{{rankHash.155}}` , output is `1`. 
But `{{rankHash.[card.furniture]}}` print same error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[card.furniture]' from 'rankHash[card.furniture]'
```

What is the appropriate answer what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a template filter to do this.

```py
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

then you can use `{{ rankHash|get_item:card.furniture }}`

Check this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating custom template tags (filters) and pass such value to the function and return the wanted value.

1. **In your app directory create a folder `templatetags`**
2. **In your created folder, create a `filters.py` file**
3. **In that same folder create the `__init__.py` file so django knows it is a module**

In your filters.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='b') #register your tag name
def yourfunction(value, arg): 
#value is the value before '|', and arg is the value assigned after ':'.
#e.g. a|b:"c",  a is value, b is the tag, c is the arg
    #do whatever you want with those values and arg
    return something
```

In your template use it like

```
{% load filters %}
...
{{rankHash|b:"somearg"}}
```

Comment: making filter is not easy for me yet... But I know this is correct way to making filter. Thank you very much